# Are variables influential in random forest also influential in svm?

Tags: svm, random-forest

This paper https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/features.pdf highlights the following approach to feature selection:

```
Repeat:
    1.  Fit a random forest model, calculate CV error
    2.  Drop bottom half of predictors based on out-of-bag variable importance
    3.  Go to step 1, stop if number of predictors < threshold

Select feature subset which minimizes CV error, and fit SVM
```

I was curious how this method works, since SVM's (RBF kernel) distance-based approach of mapping features to response is very different from the interaction-based approach of random forest.

Would variables considered influential in random forest necessarily be influential in svm?